# Wordpress: Cron job out of memory error

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cron

I have a Wordpress site with WooCommerce plugin installed. And I have created a cron job for reading emails from gmail and update product prices accordingly in the website. I have used PHP IMAP function to connect and search the mails in the inbox. Also the Wordpress cron is disabled by adding `define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true)` in WP-config.php and new cronjob is created in the server to run every hour.

```
wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'price_from_mail_event' );
add_action( 'price_from_mail_event',  'update_price_from_mail' );
function update_price_from_mail(){
    $hostname = "{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX";
    $username = "xyzmail@gmail.com";
    $password = "password";
    $inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password);
    if($inbox){
        $cement_emails = imap_search($inbox,'SUBJECT "Cement" UNSEEN'); // search unread mails with subject Cement
        $tmt_emails = imap_search($inbox,'SUBJECT "TMT" UNSEEN'); // search unread mails with subject TMT
        if($cement_emails){
            //process data and update price
        }
        if($tmt_emails){
            //process data and update price
        }
    }
}
```

The problem here is that the cron job is throwing Out of memory error(`Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 293339136) (tried to allocate 3932134 bytes) in /home/site/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php`), even if there is no unread email in inbox.

Comment: After how much time this cron job repeated ?

Comment: It runs every hour.

Comment: According to the code above, you are scheduling an event *every time WP runs*.  This doesn't seem right, and might be ending up with too many scheduled events.  Use some debugging to determine WHERE the issue is being triggered as well.  Lastly, that number references about 35 megabytes, you you likely need to allocate more memory.  However, do NOT follow the answer that advises you to modify the core file.

Comment: Check this documentation on how to increase the memory limit in WP: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/increasing-the-wordpress-memory-limit/

Comment: By the way, check how many cron jobs do you have? On the one project I have 52k of the cron jobs.

Comment: @cale_b Thanks for the suggestion. Now I have edited the code as,

`if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'price_from_mail_event' ) ) {
  wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'price_from_mail_event' );
}` 

and also found that there are no previously scheduled events. And 512MB of memory is allocated. But still getting same error.

Comment: Post the exact **new** error, please.  Just because you *think* you've allocated 512MB doesn't mean it's actually been allocated / getting used.

Comment: @cale_b here is the error I got,

`Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 290979840) (tried to allocate 3932139 bytes) in /home/site/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 434`

And how do I find the actual memory allocated?

Comment: OK, that's about 290MB (not 512MB).  Just use an online converter to convert from bytes to megabytes, and plugin in the "allocated" amount.

Comment: That should be plenty of memory, but without knowing where in your code this is being triggered it's truly impossible to tell what's going on.  (yes, it's in `wp-includes/functions.php`, but that's the `maybe_serialize` function, which is being called by *something else*, which is probably being called by something else, etc).  What are you doing in the rest of your code where you are "processing emails", etc?

Comment: I Un-sheduled the event and deleted old cron from sever and my hosting provider told me there are no cron jobs running with this hook. And now I newly created a cron to run same code and its consuming 170+MB of memory to run. I don't know why it was giving error earlier.